# Angular Js - Print array with particular key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Am new to Angular js. I wanted to print an array with particular key.

This is my array.

```
$scope.airports = {
    'PDX':{
      'code': 'PDX',
      'name': 'PDX airport',
      'destination': [
        'LAX',
        'SFO'
      ]
    },
    'STL':{
      'code':'STL',
      'name':'STL Airport',
      'destination': [
        'TLS',
        'SLT'
      ]
    },

    'MCI':{
      'code':'MCI',
      'name':'MCI Airport',
      'destination':[
        'CMI',
        'IMC'
      ]
    },

  };
```

The below code prints an array.

```
{{airports | json}}
```

The below code is printing the value of STL.

```
{{airports.STL | json}}
```

The issue is how to print the value of STL if i assign to a variable like this

In my Controller, I have set the value of airportCode

```
$scope.airportCode= "STL";
```

and in my views, i used this code to print. But it's not printing any value, and there is no error in console.

```
{{airports.airportCode | json}}
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: Important note: that is not an array, that is an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After storing airpotcode in varaible (ie `$scope.airportCode= "STL";` ) you can use this `array syntax` to access it for `$scope.airports`

```
  {{airports[airportCode] | json}}
```

**Note(by @doldt) :** $scope.airports is not an array it is an Object

Comment: @SoundharRaj glad it helped you, you can upvote and accept it as an answer so it may help others as well :)

Comment: Let's emphasise though that $scope.airports is not an array in this case, but an object.

Comment: yes, it says i have to wait for 5 more mins to accept

Comment: @doldt thanks for pointing, but i havent said its array, i said `array like syntax` :)

Comment: @A.B It wasn't a problem with your wording, but OP's, and I think the accepted answer should point that out, because the distinction is important.